# Use my Python module from my VB.NET program

Tags: python, vb.net

I have built two VB.NET projects which form client and server applications.  Now I am moving the server part to Linux and re-writing the application in Python, learning Python as I go.  There is a common part to both applications, an NMEA sentence decoder.  I have written the new decoder in Python (as a module containing classes and functions) and it is better than the VB one.  How can I use it in the client side application which will remain a VB.NET project running on Windows?  Can I turn the Python module into a DLL that I can call from VB?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you didn't use any library or facility tied to CPython, you may use IronPython to compile your code to a .NET library that you can use from VB.NET.

Comment: How do I know if I used a library that is not available in IronPython ?

Comment: Try to compile it with IronPython, if it fails on some import probably you used a library that is not available on it "out of the box" (although it may be available for installation).